# How to create capacity alert for storage container in azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I have a storage container with multiple blob storage inside it. Now i want to visualize the whole container storage size metric data in dashboard and also want to create an alert if container size crosses certain threshold in portal and not using bash or cli. How to do it?

Comment: Hello, if the answer is helpful, could you please accept it as answer? Thanks. It may help others.

Answer (score 2):

There is no built-in `alert signal` for just `one blob container`. So if you want to alert when just one container size crosses certain threshold, you should write code(like checking this blob container size periodically) to do that.

In azure, it can only alert the total of all the blob containers' size in one storage account. If you want to do that, just click the Alert menu in your storage account in azure portal, then select `your_storage_account/blob` for resource, and select `Blob Capacity` for condition to setup this kind of alert.